# Write protect single file from admin in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I know this question has to have been asked before, but it's really difficult to find the answer to the *specific* problem I have: I would like to write protect a single file *from the admin user* in Windows 7.

Here is the situation: I have an admin user that needs to able to do everything admin related on the machine *except* edit/delete/rename one specific file in the Windows\System32 directory. How do I prevent the user from doing such a thing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  We know you dont want a user to modify a file, but there has to be something more to this.  Whats the big picture here?

Comment: Blue Coat K9 Web Protection can be easily bypassed by renaming a file in the System32 directory. I want the user to be able to do all sorts of administrative tasks except bypass K9.

Comment: Then rewrite your question around that comment.  See this link, as to why.  You are trying to accomplish Y, when the real question is X.  See this article http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Keltari: A simple "NO" would have sufficed.

Comment: @davidkennedy85 - Except the answer might not not be "NO" there might be a way to do this.  I suggest you contact the company on ways they suggest access to this file.  Of course one must ask yourself why is a user even modifying this file in the first place?

Comment: The file is modified when one wishes to bypass K9. But there are many reasons why one might wish to accomplish specifically what I asked in my question, without any regard to K9. This "meta" question has been addressed here: http://superuser.com/q/539799/150178. Please forgive my frustration, but I still feel that a simple "NO" would have answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. An admin has all required privileges to gain access back to the file.